opening pdf at the cursor on lyx in Mac
I see in this post, we can open pdf at the cursor on lyx in Windows.
Is it possible in Mac?

Edit : 2024.5.24
I download Skim (a pdf viewer app in Mac).
Here is my state of LyX.
Pdf Command :
/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline $$n $$o $$t



Here is my state of Skim
Command : /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/lyxeditor
Arguments : "%file" %line; /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "LyX" to activate'

However, when I view pdf file in LyX (or press Command + R), then the pdf file is opened by the default Mac Preview app.
Can anyone help me more?

Edit : 2024.5.25
By changing 'Viewer' to Custom and write

open -a Skim.app $$i

I solve my problem.

The reverse search (from Skim to LyX) shortcut is Shift + Command + click; and the forward search (from LyX to Skim) is 'right click -> Forward Search'.
We can create a shortcut for forward search.

LyX > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts > System and Miscellaneous > forward-search

I choose a shortcut 'command + ;' for it.


Yes, you can. However, you need to use a PDF viewer which supports 'search forward' feature, such as Skim on Mac (Acrobat Reader doesn't work).
Please check the Search Forward section of Additional Help on LyX how to set up.
